# what is responsible for HDFS master (Namenode)

Tags: hdfs

Hi could anyone explain me what is HDFS master (Namenode is responsible for? also what is exactly Namenode and Datanode metadata in HDFS. I am recently started studying SPARK but our lecture was not deep enough for HDFS. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS has a master/slave architecture. An HDFS cluster consists of a single NameNode, a master server that manages the file system namespace and regulates access to files by clients. In addition, there are a number of DataNodes, usually one per node in the cluster, which manage storage attached to the nodes that they run on. HDFS exposes a file system namespace and allows user data to be stored in files. Internally, a file is split into one or more blocks and these blocks are stored in a set of DataNodes. The NameNode executes file system namespace operations like opening, closing, and renaming files and directories. It also determines the mapping of blocks to DataNodes. The DataNodes are responsible for serving read and write requests from the file system’s clients. The DataNodes also perform block creation, deletion, and replication upon instruction from the NameNode.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#NameNode+and+DataNodes

https://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-hadoop-hdfs-architecture/